# How to get the current active (selected) project path in netbeans platform API

Tags: netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

How to get the **current active (selected) project** path in netbeans platform  API.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to get the **current active project path**.

```
 import org.openide.windows.TopComponent;   
 import org.openide.filesystems.FileObject;
 import org.netbeans.api.project.FileOwnerQuery;
 import org.netbeans.api.project.Project;
//--- 
        TopComponent activeC = TopComponent.getRegistry().getActivated();
        FileObject dataLookup = activeC.getLookup().lookup(FileObject.class);
        if (dataLookup != null) {
            Project pro = FileOwnerQuery.getOwner(dataLookup);
            String path = pro.getProjectDirectory().getPath();
        }
```